# Receiving messages from SignalR Hub running on localhost when there is no activity going on

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, signalr

First of all, let me clarify that I am not sure what category this question falls in.

I am using SignalR 2.1
I have a html+javascript page on the Hub side to view all activities through the hub (by connecting to the hub as a client and printing it out to the page when there are any request to any methods within the hub)

On the other hand, I am using a .NET (WPF and/or WCF) client.
My hub is deployed on a Windows Server and accessible by all other clients connected to it.
Yes. There are activities going on as shown on the Page.

**However, when I am testing my Hub on localhost, I am getting the same activities as the one deployed on the server.**

- The endpoint is different.
- IIS is not pointed to the path of my localhost
- I made sure that IIS Express closed properly when my Hub that is run locally is closed.
- There is no other client(s) that are connected to my localhost address and to this hub.

Hoping for some explanation on what is going on here.

Comment: Thank you @Philip for the edit to enable better readability :)